# pass parameter from job to joblistener in quartz

Tags: quartz-scheduler

I am using quartz to schedule my job. Sometimes I need listener to do something after a run, but sometimes I don't need it to run.

Can I pass parameter from job instance to *joblistener*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See `JobExecutionContext.setResult()` and `getResult()`, which you can use from within the job and the listener.

Comment: Can we not use the jobDataMap to set any values within the job and then access those in joblistener ?